# Silverstripe 2.4 cms / active tab?

Tags: tabs, silverstripe

In silverstripe, when loading a page in cms the first tab (Main) is active.

Is there a way to set focus on another tab (activate) by name on load?

I'm using SS 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well guess you can do mysite.tld/admin#Root_Behaviour for example or

```
mysite.tld/admin#Root_Behaviour#Root_Content_set_Main
mysite.tld/admin#Root_Behaviour#Root_Content_set_Metadata
```

...right click on an tab and open in a other browser tab is the trick :-)